# Index a Minimum of a Subset of Data With Multiple Criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, excel-formula

I'm wondering if it is possible in Excel to index a subset of my data to find the minimum of that subset. Ideally, I would like to do this within one formula instead of having to create multiple helper areas. The closest I have come is the following formula...

```
{=INDEX(INDEX(Employees!$A$3:$A$47,MATCH(1,(B12=Employees!$B$3:$B$47)*('NEW Project'!C4<Employees!$C$3:$C$47),0)),MATCH(MIN(Employees!$J$11:$J$19),Employees!$J$11:$J$19,0))}
```

...but this formula only performs the first index and doesn't allow me to Index(Index)) all potential answers to search them to find the minimum value.

My data referred to is as follows:

```
Worksheet: Employees
A           B           C                     ...          J  
Employee | Title | Max $ Amount for Project | ... | Hours on Projects
Bert     | PM    | $35,000,000              | ... | 148
Shauna   | PM    | $15,000,000              | ... | 32
Dan      | QA    | $5,000,000               | ... | 360
```

What I'm trying to do is find a subset of my employees that are a specific position title that I enter into a cell (L2) and have a high enough Max $ Amount for Project based on a hypothetical future project value that I enter into another cell (M2) and return the one who currently has the most free time (min Hours on Projects).

e.g., $27,000,000 Project (M2), looking for a Project Manager (L2)

I want to index my list of employees to find PMs (2 of them) and grab the one of them who has the current lowest value of hours already dedicated to projects and also has the clearance to work on a project of that size. The formula would return "Bert" because he is the only one who can work on projects of that value at that position. However, if I had a new project value of $12,000,000 and was looking for a PM, the formula would return "Shauna" because she has fewer Hours on Projects currently, and can fit this new project into her less busy schedule than Bert's.

Thank you for any and all help and let me know if you need any more clarification!

Comment: Could you provide more than the column titles.  A few data points as well as which one would be the outcome would help.

Comment: Try `=Index(A:A,MATCH(J:J,MIN(IF(B:B= "Project Manager",IF(C:C >= 75000000,J:J)),0))` use ctrl-shift-enter to confirm as it is an array formula.

Comment: I have updated to include example data. 

Scott, the formula you provided returns #N/A (A value is not available to the form or function). pnuts, I have no data in C12. I'm just entering the new project value in B12 to see if I can fit it into our staff's schedules.

Comment: Yeah I had a typo, `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MIN(IF(B:B="PM",IF(C:C>=5000000,J:J))),J:J,0))`

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks for your help. If you submit that as an answer, I will be happy to select it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MIN(IF(B:B="PM",IF(C:C>=5000000,J:J))),J:J,0))
```

It is an array formula and must be applied with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

It was not understood from where the data was to be used to insert the criteria.  If L2 held the title that was wanted and M2 the minimum value the Formula would be

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MIN(IF(B:B=L2,IF(C:C>=M2,J:J))),J:J,0))
```

Comment: @pnuts, with the data given it returns the correct name, like the OP wanted.  What am I missing?

Comment: @pnuts I do not like the fact that the number(5,000,000) and title("PM") are "hard coded" and would have preferred to assign them to a cell where the data can be changed, but the OP did not give those parameters

Comment: @pnuts yeah I did not get that, that is one reason I did not put cell reference but values.   I figured that the OP could then put the cells he wanted in place.

Comment: @pnuts I think you are reading too much into it.  The OP only wanted a quick tool to mine some data on occasions.  It would only be a quick way to get some info to help.  This is not done daily.  Project of that size just don't come along that often and the output would only be one factor in deciding who is best fitted to take on the project..  That being said I am not comfortable putting my assumptions in the OP to make the Q match the A.  I am willing to edit my answer to be a little more generic.

Comment: To be honest I would have just filtered on "PM", then sort in descending order on C and then column J ascending.  It would have given the exact same answer.

Comment: Hey guys, I appreciate your discussion regarding the answer. I did tweak the formula on my end to include the cell references rather than the coded values. Was there something else you had wanted me to change in the question?